# PL/SQL : How to run the sql statements stored within a column of the table to get the execution time of the sql statement?

Tags: function, plsql, oracle11g, package

I have some difficulty in writing my pl sql script. This is the scenario:

I have Table A which have 2 Columns namely Column 1(varchar), Column 2(varchar) as shown below.

```
Table A

       Column 1              Column 2
Row 1   a               select * from table_one
Row 2   b               select * from table_two 
Row 3   c               select * from table_three
```

I have created a package: pg_creating_package which contains a main function func_loop, which will eventually loop in each row of the table and execute each sql stored in Column 2, one by one and insert the time taken in the final table B for example:

```
Table B

              Start time               End time       Time Taken
Row 1   27/04/2014 12:33:44   27/04/2014 12:35:44       2mins  
Row 2   27/04/2014 12:33:44   27/04/2014 12:33:45       1sec
```

and so on...

My questions are :
1. How will i run the sql statements stored within that column?
2. How will i get the start time of the sql statement?
3. How will i get the ending time of the sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'your select statement'` or `DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE` .
To record execution time, get time before and after `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

```
DECLARE   
start_time TIMESTAMP;  
end_time TIMESTAMP;  
BEGIN  
 ....
 start_time := SYSTIMESTAMP;  
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '....';  
 end_time := SYSTIMESTAMP;  
 .....  
END;
```

You may want to use [DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1002765) instead of datetime/timestamp.

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried what you suggested but getting the following error: PLS-00382
Infact my function func_loop is returning NUMBER. But the following statement returns type DATE, I think.

diff_time :=  mod(trunc(24 * 60 * (end_time - start_time)), 60);
where diff_time is the difference between end_time and start_time 

Do you have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: what is type of `end_time` and `start_time` ? `trucn` doesn't work with `TIMESTAMP`, only with `DATE`. Cast to date, or use `dbms_utility.get_time` which is more precise especially with small intervals.

Comment: end_time and start_time is of type number. start_date and end_date is of type date since i want the date itself to be displayed. diff_time is the time taken from start_time till end_time.    

start_date:=  SYSTIMESTAMP;    
start_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;    
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "....."; 
end_date:=  SYSTIMESTAMP;  
end_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;    
diff_time := round( (end_time - start_time) / 100, 2);    
Still not working!